# Oracle database recovery

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery

I was living in Ukraine, Kharkov. Now moved to another place due to war with Russian. Back there in Kharkov I had HP ProLiant server with Oracle database. Before escape city I did copy of file system to my laptop. Oracle Linux installed on laptop.

Is it possible to restore/run database instance with all my database schemas/users from that copy of filesystem?

I'm Java and PL/SQL developer. But I'm not Oracle administer, Oracle is quite complex system and it hard to run it for me from copy of filesystem.

As well, I managed to get all 4 SAS drives from server and took them with me. But I do not have a server here, I'll try to find someone who has one.

Please guide me or give some ideas what could I do to run database again. Or export and import data to new database.

Comment: If you made a full copy of the disc, then you should be able to restore. Maybe ask this question better at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's included in your filesystem copy? If you included the Oracle software installation (the Oracle Home of the database) and all the database files (including data files, control files, redo log files), you can very likely directly startup your database after moving everything to original path, and create relevant OS users and groups (usually user `oracle`, groups `oinstall` and `dba`) with matching ID's.

Warning: If possible, backup before experimenting with starting up. Failure of starting an Oracle database might cause further damage (though very unlikely).

Comment: Hi, how is this going? Have you managed to install the Oracle Database Software (exact same version) on your new OS? Have you manged to place all database files in their respective folders?

Comment: @FatP Yes, I have copy of everything, Oracle instance and all database files. Actually I even managed to take 4 SAS server drivers from server and get away with them.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt Thank you. I managed to find cheap replacement for server in place where I'm now. So I believe I'll just put my 4 hard drives in server. Setup RAID array in appropriate way. Then I hope database will get up without any issues!

Comment: Thank you a lot for you suggestions and questions. I'm waiting when another server will be delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work if you have the same file paths as on your original Oracle database.

1. Create new database.
2. Shutdown immediate;
3. Change your command window to the same directory that the backups are in.
4. Launch RMAN with new database as target

The following are the rman commands you will be issuing:

```
 startup nomount;
 restore controlfile from '<<file path to control file>>';
 shutdown immediate;
 startup mount;
 restore database;
 recover database;
 alter database open resetlogs;
```